# How to close popover after certain interval in Angular?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap-popover

I am using Angular(14) and ngxbootstrap(https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/popover?tab=overview). I am unable to see closing the popover automatically after certain interval. It has show()/hide() functions but how do we achieve this? Show the popover and close after certain interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/popover?tab=overview#trigger-by-isopen-property) you can use the `isOpen` attribute to close the popover.

Using the example provided in their documentation:

```html
<p>
  <span popover="Hello there! I was triggered by changing isOpen property"
    triggers=""  [isOpen]="isOpen">
    This text has attached popover
  </span>
</p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
  (click)="isOpen = !isOpen">
  Toggle
</button>
```

You could bind a function to the click event that would trigger a timeout to close your popover:

Add the `onPopOverClick` method in the `.html` file:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
  (click)="onPopOverClick()">
  Toggle
</button>
```

And in the `.ts` file:

```js
onPopOverClick(): void {
  this.isOpen = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.isOpen = false;
  }, 5000); // the delay before popover closes automatically
}
```